# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin'. > Compilation error. See log for more details

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, testing, android-jetpack-compose

I am currently developing an app using Jetpack Compose on android studio Dolphin. Im trying to run some integration tests of my project but when i do i get the following error. Yesterday when i ran it it went fine, i tried to compare the changes between yesterday before working and now and i don't see anything that might have caused this.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details
```

This is my Build Gradle (:app) file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myfirstapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myfirstapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }


    testOptions {
        packagingOptions {
            jniLibs {
                useLegacyPackaging = true
            }
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        debug {

            buildConfigField("String", "SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID", "\"8b6c688dfa0846e28eec2cada09d9835\"")
            buildConfigField(
                    "String",
                    "SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI_AUTH",
                    "\"comexamplemyfirstapplication://callback\""
            )
            buildConfigField(
                    "String",
                    "SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI_PKCE",
                    "\"comexamplemyfirstapplication://callback\""
            )
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField("String", "SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID", "\"8b6c688dfa0846e28eec2cada09d9835\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI_AUTH", "\"comexamplemyfirstapplication://callback\"")
            buildConfigField("String", "SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI_PKCE", "\"comexamplemyfirstapplication://callback\"")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.1.1'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_ui_version"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-runtime-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_ui_version"
    androidTestImplementation project(path: ':app')
    androidTestImplementation project(path: ':app')
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_ui_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_ui_version"
    def nav_version = "2.5.3"
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version")


    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.0')

    // Declare the dependencies for the desired Firebase products without specifying versions
    // For example, declare the dependencies for Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx"

    //add extended icons
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_ui_version"

    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.1.0"


    // Local unit tests
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.5.1"
    testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3"
    testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.9.1"
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.10.5"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.1.0-alpha04"

    // Instrumentation tests
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.37'
//    kaptAndroidTest 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.37'
    androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    androidTestImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.5.1"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0"
    androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:1.1.3"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.9.1"
    androidTestImplementation "io.mockk:mockk-android:1.10.5"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'

//SPOTIFY
    implementation files('../app-remote-lib/spotify-app-remote-release-0.7.2.aar')
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0"
    implementation 'com.spotify.android:auth:1.2.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'

    implementation("com.adamratzman:spotify-api-kotlin-android:3.8.6")

    androidTestImplementation 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker:2.21.0'

}
```

and the Build Gradle (Project) file

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_ui_version = '1.1.1'
    }

    //add this dependency
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14' //or try .10
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}
```

This is what the debug log says

```
2023-06-20 14:09:09.965 19707-21001/? E/DG: FSC error [CONTEXT service_id=25 ]
    java.io.IOException: Couldn't fetch response.
        at afwq.a(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):20)
        at afui.c(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):5)
        at afui.b(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):0)
        at afup.a(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):49)
        at com.google.android.gms.droidguard.DroidGuardChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):6)
        at com.google.android.gms.framework.tracing.wrapper.TracingIntentService.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):1)
        at hfu.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):0)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: awdn: Failed to process request
        at bly.n(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):3)
        at bly.get(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):19)
        at bmd.get(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):2)
        at afwq.a(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):18)
        at afui.c(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):5) 
        at afui.b(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):0) 
        at afup.a(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):49) 
        at com.google.android.gms.droidguard.DroidGuardChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):6) 
        at com.google.android.gms.framework.tracing.wrapper.TracingIntentService.onHandleIntent(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):1) 
        at hfu.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):0) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67) 
     Caused by: awdn: Failed to process request
        at awfb.onFailed(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):2)
        at jf.onFailed(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_cronetdynamite@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-0):0)
        at ih.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_cronetdynamite@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-0):1)
        at achn.c(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):6)
        at achn.run(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):7)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
        at acmt.run(:com.google.android.gms@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-540586286):0)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
     Caused by: iq: Exception in CronetUrlRequest: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, ErrorCode=1, InternalErrorCode=-105, Retryable=false
        at org.chromium.net.impl.CronetUrlRequest.onError(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_cronetdynamite@232216047@23.22.16 (190800-0):5)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full error log?